# How to iterate properly from 0.0 to 1.0 in a 'for' loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, floating-point, iteration, normalize

This is a fairly simple question, yet I am struggling to find an elegant solution for!

Suppose you want to iterate from `0.0` to `1.0` in discrete steps, you'll use a `for` loop that uses `int` since it's discouraged to use `float` due to precision errors.

The simplest approach is the following but it's flawed as it never outputs `1.0`:

```
private void sample1(int steps = 100)
{
    var floats = new float[steps]; // 100 values

    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) // goes from 0 to 99
    {
        var f = 1.0f / steps * i; // will only go from 0.0 to 0.99, never reaches 1.0

        floats[i] = f;
    }
}
```

A first attempt to address the issue, it works but we end with one more value:

```
private void sample2(int steps = 100)
{
    var n = steps + 1;

    var floats = new float[n]; // 101 values now!

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) // goes from 0 to 100
    {
        var f = 1.0f / n * i; // goes from 0.0 to 1.0 but now we have an extra value

        floats[i] = f;
    }
}
```

A second attempt to address the issue, we don't have an extra value but last is never really `1.0`:

```
private void sample3(int steps = 100)
{
    var floats = new float[steps]; // 100 values

    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) // goes from 0 to 99
    {
        var f = 1.0f / steps * i * ((steps - 1.0f) / steps); // goes from 0.0 to 0.999...

        floats[i] = f;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How does one properly loop from `0.0` to `1.0` as discrete steps in a `for` loop that uses `int`?

(pseudo-code is just fine)

Comment: What is this weird formula in your last example? Have you tried simply `1.0f * i / (steps - 1)`?

Comment: Why not use **var floats = new float [steps + 1]**. Would give the result 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: If you include 0.00 and 1.00 and step by 0.01 you'll end up with 101 values. That should be expected. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @tkausl No I didn't but it turns out to be the solution to my problem!

Comment: @AlbertoSantos The user specifies he wants `100` points, not `101` points as I've explained.

Comment: @Fildor The actual value of `step` is irrelevant, it's the number of steps and that they exactly cover from `0.0` to `1.0` that is important.

Comment: @tkausl that formula was to 'scale' the value but it never fully reached `1.0`.

Comment: So, what I mean is that 0.0 to 0.9 is the 100 he wants. If he wants it to show from 0.0 to 1.0 then there would be 101 steps.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, @tkausl might want to make an answer out of his comment ...

Comment: To get 10 values, going from 0.0 to 1.0 in equal steps, you will need to produce the values 0.0, 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.444444444, 0.555555555, 0.6666666666, 0.77777777777, 0.8888888889, 1.0 (with some rounding errors here and there, and I didn't bother getting the same number of fractional digits in my examples). If the user *also* expects to get the values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc. then you're going to have a problem if you also want to include 0.0 and 1.0 in the list, because that makes 11 numbers.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes I understand now, and it was my actual problem.

Comment: FYI, use `1.0f * i / steps` rather than `1.0f / steps * i`. As long as `steps` is a reasonable size, the former has one rounding error instead of two. Sometimes the latter will not equal 1 even when `i` equals `steps`. (For example, `1.0f / 41 * 41` produces 0.999999940395355224609375 in IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count out loud to 10. If you *included* zero in your counting, you actually spoke out *eleven* numbers, not 10. Since you want to *include* zero without making any progress towards your goal of `1.0f`, the other **`steps-1`** slices of 1.0f must sum up to 1.0.

Or to think about it from another angle:

To get 1 your numerator and denominator need to be equal. Since your for-loop runs from 0 to `steps` exclusive, *or `steps-1` inclusive*, your denominator *must be `steps-1`*.

Comment: Thank you, simple and effective! (and definitely makes sense)